# GNU make: how to add all files from a directory to a variable?

Tags: gnu-make

Using GNU make, how do I add all files with extension `.x` from a directory to a variable list?

This does not work:
`ALL_X := all_x/*.x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the manual for information on [the `wildcard` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html):

```
ALL_X := $(wildcard all_x/*.x)
```